# Swift: taking reference of object's property with ampersand (&) causing compiler error

Tags: arrays, swift, compiler-errors, pass-by-reference

This is a rather straightforward issue. Consider an array:

```
var array = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7]
```

I wish to swap the first and the last element of the array, using the standard `swap` function:

```
swap(&array[0], &array[array.count - 1])
```

However there exists another way to obtain the first and last elements of an array, which is to use `Array`'s built-in properties `first` and `last`. It follows that this code should also work:

```
swap(&array.first!, &array.last!)
```

However this time the compiler complains that `Type of expression is ambiguous without more context`. I wonder how I can modify the expression so that the compiler can parse it correctly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`first` is a read-only property, therefore you cannot modify the array
through `array.first`.

```
swap(&array[0], &array[array.count - 1])
```

works because `subscript()` of mutable collection types has both setter
and getter.

Not that I recommend it, but if you define your own read-write properties

```
extension Array {
    var myFirst: T {
        get { return self[0] }
        set { self[0] = newValue }
    }
    var myLast: T {
        get { return self[count - 1] }
        set { self[count - 1] = newValue }
    }
}
```

(which assume that the array it not empty) then

```
swap(&array.myFirst, &array.myLast)
```

works as expected.